# using libusb header file

Tags: c++

I need to communicate with USB port by C++. so I searched the web and found a comppresd (.rar) file. Its name is `usblib-1.0.9.tar.bz2`. I extracted it and it contains several files and folders and some of them are header files (*.h). I think my necessary file is one of them that its name is `libusb.h`.

Moreover in this comppresed file there are some example programs to communicate via USB. I copied one of them to a C++ empty program for testing. This program uses libusb header file as one of library.

I added libusb.h to this program (right click on Header Files in solution explorer and choose `add > existing item` then browse `libusb.h`), but this library (`libusb.h`) is still unspecified (`#include <libusb.h>` is unspecified ) and I can't debug this example program. Do I need to do another action to add this new library (`libusb.h`) to use in this program?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by unspecified. Do you mean you get a compile time error for that line, or do you get this message when adding the .h to the project?

Comment: no, i dont have any problem when i add the header file, but when i debug the example program an error accourd

Comment: How did you include this into the project. I am struggling to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows you can use libusb-win32, that can be found in:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/

It can be helpful.
Thanks